# unsigned long long unexpected behaviour in Xcode clang compiler

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang, llvm-clang

I am trying something on my Mac OS X XCode 7.2.1 -

```
#define uint64 unsigned long long

int N = 100000;
uint64 value = (pow(N, 4) + 2 * pow(N, 3) + 3 * pow(N, 2) + 2 * N) / 4;
cout << "value: " << value << endl; // this is equivalent to ULLONG_MAX (18446744073709551615)
cout << "ULLONG_MAX: " << ULLONG_MAX << endl;
```

So the output is supposed to be -

```
value: 18446744073709551615
ULLONG_MAX: 18446744073709551615
```

But the output is -

```
value: 0
ULLONG_MAX: 18446744073709551615
```

Also below changes didn't make any difference.

```
uint64 N = 100000ull;
uint64 value = (pow(N, 4ull) + 2ull * pow(N, 3ull) + 3ull * pow(N, 2ull) + 2ull * N) / 4ull;
```

Running `gcc --version` command on my terminal yields -

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

I tried above code in Hackerrank g++ 4.9.2 compiler and the output was correct.

What's happening under the hood? Is it Clang or my OS(Mac OS X 10.11)?

Comment: If you assign to `long double` instead, you'll see that the result is _not_ `ULLONG_MAX`.  Instead, it would overflow.  `long double value = pow(N, 4.0L) + 2.0L * pow(N, 3.0L) + 3.0L * pow(N, 2.0L) + 2.0L * N) / 4.0L;`

Comment: Thank you :) `long double` can hold more data which is certainly helpful to check if any overflow occurs in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by overflow. Your equation returns: [25000500007500050000](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(100000%5E4%20%2B%202%20*%20100000%5E3%20%2B%203%20*%20100000%5E2%20%2B%202%20*%20100000)%20%2F%204) which is to large for an unsigned long long.

It would seem like clang handles this slightly differently from g++. I made a small test to see what the result became after the cast.

See: [Clang giving random values](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c29cd5bf80476288) while [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e41f53198e2a72a) returns `std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max()`.

---

Should you need this number (in a datatype) I would personally advise finding a library that supports arbitrary length numbers (gmp or comparable).

Comment: Thank you. I guessed almost same thing as you, just happy to be sure about it :) Specially for my problem, handling with `unsigned long long` has passed all the test cases so I won't need to deal with big integer or similar thing this time.